# Regexp python - finding substring

Tags: python, regex

How could I find all instances of a substring in a string?

For example I have the string (`"%1 is going to the %2 with %3"`). I need to extract all placeholders in this string (`%1`, `%2`, `%3`)

The current code could only find the first two because the ending is not a white space.

```
import re
string = "%1 is going to the %2 with %3"


r = re.compile('%(.*?) ')
m = r.finditer(string)
for y in m:
 print (y.group())
```

Answer (score 5):

Don't match on whitespace, match on a word boundary instead using `\b`:

```
r = re.compile(r'%(.*?)\b')
```

You may want to restrict your characters to word characters only instead of the `.` wildcard, and match *at least one* character:

```
r = re.compile(r'%(\w+)\b')
```

You don't appear to be using the capturing group either, so you could just omit that:

```
r = re.compile(r'%\w+\b')
```

Comment: Thanks Martijn, what if the placeholder was to change from %1 to %1%, how could I extract that entire substring?

Comment: Then you can just match on the second `%`: `r'%(\w+)%'`.

Comment: What if that is an unknown character, it could be a %, $ or even %%?

Comment: Only word-constituents would pose a problem (matching `\w`) for obvious reasons.

Comment: @user1322582: what are you trying to do? You can create a dynamic regular expression, or you can use a character class to match the possible characters: `r'(?P<meta>(%|%%|$|$$)\w+(?P=meta)'` would match one of 4 different meta characters, provided that the *same* meta character(s) are used *after* the name as well.

Comment: I need the script to find all placeholders in a string. The problem is that the placeholder format is unpredictable (eg. "%n", "%1%%", "%(string)"). I would need to generalize the script to just find all substrings that begin with an %, and extract it.

Comment: @user1322582: Then what constitutes a pattern? It always starts with `%` and ends before a space or the end of the string? You need to be explicit about such details.

Comment: It ends at the end of the string, I found another thread you were involved in that had a similar situation, I worked with the regexp and this works: re.compile(r'(?:^|.)(\%\S+)')